# How to call function in .so file using dlopen() and dlsym()?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

With the help of [Shared libraries with GCC on Linux](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) I tried to make `libadd1.so` and succeeded. The code runs perfectly.
But when I tried the same thing using `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` I got errors as shown below.

```
$ g++ -L/home/shreya/Desktop/soFiles -Wall -o test main.c -ladd1
main.c: In function ‘int main()’:
main.c:14:14: warning: variable ‘ptrVar’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  pt2function ptrVar;
              ^
/tmp/ccpdIje6.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `dlopen'
main.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `dlerror'
main.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `dlerror'
main.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `dlsym'
main.c:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `dlerror'
main.c:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

Can any one tell me what's wrong?

Comment: not linking with `-ldl`

Comment: Did you include the header ?

Comment: @ameyCU: Why not including a header should result in a linker error?

Comment: @Klaus Yes, it was a stupid question. Sorry for that .

Comment: I had already include header file regarding which it gives errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the manpage. For Linux, you have to link with `-ldl` for using the dynamic linking functions. This is a bit of a hassle because e.g. on FreeBSD, they are part of the standard library.

BTW, linking the library that you want to open dynamically (in your case `-ladd1`) doesn't make sense.

Comment: using a "proper" build-system should fix the problem of sometimes-nedding to link with `-ldl`; e.g. autotools or whatever you prefer.